# Sed invalid range end

Tags: regex, sed

I have strings like these:

```
volume 5

vol. 5

V. 5

v. 5
```

I'm trying to turn them into this format:

```
\textbf{5}
```

with this sed command

```
s/\(v[a-Z]*[.]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\1 \\textbf{\2}/
```

but I keep getting `invalid range end`. Am I doing something wrong with the 0-9 range?

Comment: `a-Z` should be `a-zA-Z`

Comment: Maybe http://ideone.com/vajhPy?

Comment: What is your LANG variable set to? Try setting it to en_US.UTF-8 if it's C.

Comment: @WD_2T Did any of the answers below work?

Answer (score 4):

If you check the ASCII table, you will see that `a` value is higher than the value of `Z`. This creates an invalid range. Moreover, you need a case-insensitive pattern, add `/I` modifier (**for GNU `sed` only**):

```
echo 'volume 5' | sed 's/\(v[a-z]*[.]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\1 \\textbf{\2}/gI'
echo 'vol. 5' | sed 's/\(v[a-z]*[.]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\1 \\textbf{\2}/gI'
echo 'V. 5' | sed 's/\(v[a-z]*[.]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\1 \\textbf{\2}/gI'
echo 'v. 5' | sed 's/\(v[a-z]*[.]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\1 \\textbf{\2}/gI'
```

[produces](https://ideone.com/yY2JRh)

```
volume \textbf{5}
vol. \textbf{5}
V. \textbf{5}
v. \textbf{5}
```

Since the BSD implementation of `sed` does not support case-insensitive matching, on macOS, you need to install GNU `sed` with the following brew command:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

and then use

```
gsed -e 's/\(v[a-z]*[.]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\1 \\textbf{\2}/gI'
```

etc.

Or, add the uppercase letters to the bracket expression:

```
sed 's/\(v[a-zA-Z]*[.]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\1 \\textbf{\2}/g'
```

And if you want to make sure only ASCII letters are matched add

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/\(v[a-zA-Z]*[.]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\1 \\textbf{\2}/g'
```

Comment: Changing `[A-z]` => `[a-zA-Z]` fixed my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sed -r "s/([vV][a-zA-Z]*[.]*) ([0-9]*)/\1 \\\textbf{\2}/"
```